# Excel VBA question - If then ElseIf statement

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA conditional function I hacked together (I'm a noob) that checks for a name in a cell and then returns appropriate variations if one of the conditions is true, otherwise it returns a blank "".  Instead of returning a blank, I'd like it to return the default cell value.

As an example, I have the following cells and results based on my function:

```
   Cells
   A        B
1  Bob      Bob Rob Robert
2  Mike     Mike Michael
3  Dan      Dan Daniel
4  Scott
```

I'd like the result for B4 to return the default value in A4 (Scott), rather then a blank, like this:

```
   Cells
   A        B
1  Bob      Bob Rob Robert
2  Mike     Mike Michael
3  Dan      Dan Daniel
4  Scott    Scott
```

Any help would be appreciated:

Here's my function (abbreviated version without all names included in ElseIf):

```
Function NameList(pVal As String) As String

    If pVal = "Bob" Then
        NameList = "Bob Rob Robert"
    ElseIf pVal = "Mike" Then
        NameList = "Mike Michael"
    ElseIf pVal = "Dan" Then
        NameList = "Dan Daniel"
    Else
        NameList = ""
    End If

End Function
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think
`Else

  NameList = pVal`
solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Take a good look at the else clause:

```
 [...]
 Else
     NameList = ""
 End If
```

The function returns the empty string (`""`) if none of the if/elseif clauses matches.

If your function is called with `pVal="Scott"` you fall through to the default assignment. What would you like it to be instead of the empty string?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know whether I understand your question correctly but try this

```
Function NameList(pVal As String) As String

If pVal = "Bob" Then
    NameList = "Bob Rob Robert"
ElseIf pVal = "Mike" Then
    NameList = "Mike Michael"
ElseIf pVal = "Dan" Then
    NameList = "Dan Daniel"
Else
    NameList = pVal
End If

End Function
```